# Determine where the hessian matrix is indefinite for $f(x,y) = x^y$

Tags: analysis, inequality

I need to find the area in which the hessian matrix for $f(x,y) = x^y, x > 0$ is indefinite.

I did so:

1) $\begin{pmatrix} y\cdot(y-1)\cdot x^{y-2} & x^{y-1} \cdot (1+y\cdot ln(x)) \\ x^{y-1} \cdot (1+y\cdot ln(x)) & x^y \cdot ln(x)^2 \end{pmatrix}$.

2) Hessian matrix is indefinite, if its determinant is < 0.

3) $\det H_f (x,y) = -x^{2y-2} \cdot (1+ 2y \cdot ln(x) + y \cdot ln(x)^2)$.

so the second part has to be greater than 0. Which means that

4) $y \cdot ln(x) \cdot (2 + ln(x)) > -1$.

5) Here I had several cases. However, comparing it to the 3DPlot this seems a bit weird.

I got

- $ x = 1 \rightarrow$ for any y it is indefinite.
- $ x = e^{-2} \rightarrow$ for any y it is indefinite.
- $ x > 1 \rightarrow$; if x is close to 1 we have $y > -\infty$; if x becomes larger then we have $y > -0,0000..00001$ like this.
- $ 0 < x < e^{-2} \rightarrow$; if x is close to 0, we have $y > -0,0000..00001$; if x is close to $e^{-2}$ we have $y > -\infty$.
- $ x = e^{-1} \rightarrow$ we nicely have $ y > 1$.
- $ e^{-2} < x < 1$; if x is close to $e^{-2}$ we have $y > \infty$; if x is close to $e^{-1}$ from upper/lower side we have $y > 1,00000...1$; if x is close to 1 we have $y > \infty$.

I created a picture; with red colour I painted the area in which the hessian matrix is indefinite.
http://postimg.org/image/3t963qmi5/

Comment: Hint: the second part equals $y(\ln(x)+1)^2+1-y$. Now consider the cases $y<0$ and $y>0$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I got almost the same results; the only difference is that I made a mistake with the inequalities above: the last second lines are wrong: $x = e^{-1} \rightarrow$ we nicely have $y < 1$ -- $ e^{-2} < x < 1$; if x is close to $e^{-2} $we have $y < \infty$; if x is close to $e^{-1}$ we have $y < 1.000000...1$; if x is close to 1 we have $y < \infty$. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have $y(\ln(x)+1)^2+1-y>0\iff y((\ln(x)+1)^2-1)>-1$. Now $(\ln(x)+1)^2-1<0\iff-1<\ln(x)+1<1\iff 0<\ln(x)+2<2\iff x>e^{-2}\lor x<1$. Then $y(\ln(x)+1)^2+1-y>0\iff y<\frac{1}{1-(\ln(x)+1)^2}$.  Treat the case $e^{-2}<x<1$ similar.